# C# / XNA Line Rectangle Collision/Response

Tags: c#, xna, geometry, collision-detection, xna-4.0

To start with, I have a simple class, `Line`;

```
public class Line
{
    public Vector2 P1 = Vector2.Zero;
    public Vector2 P2 = Vector2.Zero;

    public Line(Vector2 p1, Vector2 p2)
    {
        P1 = p1;
        P2 = p2;
    }
}
```

A list of all lines in the game, and my sprites bounding rectangle. I'm trying to find whether or not this rectangles bottom middle is below the point on the line it's directly above, and update it to the point on the line it's at. This picture might help you understand what I mean;
[image]

The rectangle is moving down, passes it's intersection point, then updates accordingly.

Any ideas on how you could go about this? I can easily find which line it's currently above, but I don't know how to get the point on the line it's above and keep it from falling past that point.

Code samples or references would be great.

Comment: Is the box always going to be in the same orientation or can it be falling at any angle?

Comment: Just a side-note: You should be *very* weary about doing collision response with point or line objects. There is massive potential for floating-point precision problems. Consider using solid shapes (rectangles, triangles, etc) instead.

Comment: **@ Izcd:** It is an axis aligned rectangle, no rotation. **@ Andrew:** Well, I'm trying to create a more 'organic' editor for my game, and it seems lots of editors use 'lines' to determine their collisions. Like this one for example: [Dust:AET Editor](http://www.gamasutra.com/db_area/images/feature/180520/dustaet_03_large.jpg). How would one go about implementing collisions like this?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the locations of the endpoints of the line, then it's pretty trivial to get the equation of that line in the form y = mx + c. Then you need to find the midpoint of the bottom of that rectangle - seeing as the XNA rectangle gives you its height, width and centre point location, this is also trivial. From there, you take the x co-ordinate of your rectangle centre point, use the y = mx + c equation to work out the y co-ordinate of your line at that point. Then you just need to check whether the rectangle's bottom centre is below that point, and if it is, use your rectangle's height value to work out how far above that y co-ordinate you need to put the rectangle so that it appears to sit on the line. Should be simple enough.

Comment: Ah, somebody finally answered! Yay. Yea, I knew it had something to do with the center point and slope intercept, but maybe I just needed somebody to spell it out for me. I'll try it out in a bit and get back to you.